# Is there any way to set the type of route's data in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

After working in Angular for a while, I realised that we don't have any data type set in route's data subscribers. So, for example,  with the following route's configuration:

```js
{
  path: '',
  data: {
    name: 'Bob' // type: string
  },
  resolve: {
    cars: CarsResolver // resolves to type: Car[]
  }
}
```

when subscribing to the route's data we're not able to know what type of data is expected

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.data.subscribe(data => 
    data.cars // type: any
    // data is a type of Data, unfortunately there's nothing like this.route.data<type>
  });
}
```

This would be useful for intellisense to work correctly, and of course to catch all kinds of errors while compiling. Is there currently any way to specify the data structure? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The data property is meant to hold various static data. I doubt there is a way to type it. Have you considered casting the data value when using in a component?

Comment: Yeah, casting them would be a possibility, but I was wondering that maybe Angular has already implemented something to deal with it. The Data object could be a default option, but as the rest of Angular is strictly typed (which in my opinion is a good thing) this seems a bit odd to me that there's no option to specify that structure. There is a library that I've just found [ngx-typed-router](https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-typed-router) but I would prefer some "native" solution if it'd be available. Thank you @R.Richards

Comment: Also, this wouldn't really be a thing (or at least it would be less dangerous) if it dealt only with the static data, but the resolvers are available in the data after they resolve and this may be the cause some of the bugs.